# Assign Role When User Registration in "AspNet Membership"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-membership, asp.net-roles

In my AspNetRoles Table I have two roles

### Id| Name

1 | HEI_Admin

2 | HEI_User

this is my View Class drop down to select the user role when user register

```
                     <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleName,
                                                      new SelectList(
                                                      new List<Object>{ 
                                                      new { value = "" , text = "Select"  },
                                                      new { value = "HEC_Admin" , text = "Higher Edcuation Council" },
                                                      new { value = "HEI_User" , text = "Higher Education Institute"}
                                                      }, "value", "text", "-"), new { id = "allDay" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleName)

                    </div>
```

this  is front end Javascript for above drop down

```
    <script>
        $("#allDay").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "HEC_Admin") {
                $("#University").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#Direct_Number").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#Mobile").attr("disabled", true);
            }
            else if($(this).val() == "HEI_User") {
                $("#University").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#Direct_Number").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#Mobile").attr("disabled", false);
            }

        });

    </script>
```

this is where i call model class

```
  public class RegisterViewModel
  {
     // rest of 

     public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

this where I assign Role to user when user registration

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName} ;
                user.Email = model.Email;


                user.ConfirmedEmail = false;

                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Name);

                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
```

when I use webpages membership this procedure working perfectly , but In here I'm using AspNet membership , here I'm getting following error

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections**

Comment: Your question is really confusing. Your code is **ASP.Net Identity**, but you keep saying **AspNet Membership**. Then you introduce a new word - **webpages membership**. Error message is basically saying it cannot find SQL Server. **Can you access SQL server via SSMS?**

Comment: simply , how to populate date in "AspNetRoles" table when user register ?